# Truncating 2 byte variable to 1 byte

Tags: assembly, nasm

This seems like a a trivial question, but I'm lost.

In this example `character` is a 2 byte variable, while the register `bx` is a single byte. I'm trying to do `cmp bx, [character]`, which clearly won't work because of the difference in size.

I'm trying to compare `bx` to only the first byte of `character`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**bx** rebister is 16 bit size and is composed from two 8 bit **bl** and **bh**!

For 16 bit cmp you can use prefix:

```
cmp bx, word ptr[character]
```

for 8 bit **bl** cmp

```
 cmp bl, byte ptr[character]
```

or 8 bit **bh** cmp

```
 cmp bh, byte ptr[character + 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the first byte (not the second), so cmp bh, byte ptr[character + 0] did the job.

Comment: The prefix isn't needed (or shouldn't be). A decent assembler can figure out that `bl` will compare to a byte and `bx` to a word.